# Smooth affine structures

Tags: dynamical-systems, smooth-manifolds

In the book "Introduction to the Modern Theory of Dynamical Systems" the author uses the term "smooth affines structures". [image]

What is this structure really?

Proposition $2.1.3:$ Let $I = [-\delta,\delta ]$, $f: I\to I$ be a real analytic contracting
map, $f(0) = 0$, and $\mu :=f'(0) \neq 0$. Then there are an interval $J_1 \subset I$ containing
$0$ and a real-analytic diffeomorphism $h: J_1 \to J_2 \subset \mathbb{R}$ preserving the origin and
conjugating $f$ with the linear map $\Lambda(x)= \mu x$.

Comment: What is the assertion of Proposition 2.1.3?

Comment: Let $I = [-\delta,\delta ]$, $f: I\to I$ be a real analytic contracting
map, $f(0) = 0$, and $\mu :=f'(0) \neq 0$. Then there are an interval $J_1 \subset I$ containing
$0$ and a real-analytic diffeomorphism $h: J_1 \to J_2 \subset \mathbb{R}$ preserving the origin and
conjugating $f$ with the linear map $\Lambda(x)= \mu x$.

Comment: The general terminology is that a (flat) affine structure on a manifold is a special atlas where the transition maps are restrictions of affine maps.